# How to work with extern in different files

Tags: c++, extern

I have these files structure:

### main.cpp

```
#include "main.h"
Map map;
Fruit fruit;
Stone stone;
```

### main.h

```
extern Map map;
extern Fruit fruit;
extern Stone stone;
```

### map.h

```
#include "main.h"
class Map {public: int size = 20;};
```

### fruit.h

```
#include "main.h"
class Fruit { public: int pos = 1; draw() {return map.size;} };
```

### stone.h

```
#include "main.h"
class Stone { public: draw() {return map.size * fruit.pos;} };
```

The problem is when I'm trying to use `map.size` and `fruit.pos` I get error:

```
'map': undeclared identifier
```

The same with `stone`. So, what's wrong?

Comment: please post real code. I fixed the most obvious typos, but you have `;` missing all over the place

Comment: @idclev463035818 added semicolons, please review.

Comment: @Eljay thank you for your help. I forgot about semicolons because it's the most unimportant part of this topic.

Comment: Only `#include` what the file (`*.h` or `*.cpp`) actually depends on.  Don't `#include` files that the file does not depend on.  Use header guards (`#ifndef FRUIT_H` `#define FRUIT_H` ... `#endif`).

Comment: @Eljay I have updated the code in post. Please, revise.

Comment: stone.h depends on 3 files:  main.h, map.h and fruit.h.  Yet it only includes none of those.  main.h has no dependencies, so it should include no header files, but it does need forward declarations of `class Map; class Fruit; class Stone;`.  Much of the confusion would be cleared up if the implementation of Map, Fruit, and Stone were in their own `*.cpp` files instead of as inline methods.  It's also very brittle to have hard-coded dependences to map and fruit rather than having them passed in as parameters.

Comment: @Eljay john from answer below said me to remove `main.h` from all the files, except `main.cpp`. So, should `stone.h` include it or not?

Comment: They are dependent on `main.h` so they should have an include.  But it would be far better to remove the hard-coded dependency altogether, because it's odd.

Comment: @Eljay can you please describe your recommended realization in new answer?

Comment: you should not fix problems in your code in the question according to an answer. Your question should contain code that produces the compiler error your question is about and not many other compiler errors.

Comment: i reverted your edit (and added `;`) because you should not change your question substantially after you got an answer. Both answers were answering a question that was not present anymore. Next time please make sure that the code you post does produce the error you claim

Answer (score 2):

`main.h` should include `map.h` not the other way around.

`main.h` should include `fruit.h` not the other way around.

`main.h` should include `stone.h` not the other way around.

Also you should add [include guards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) to your header files.

EDIT

Here's one way that works, (I can't believe I recommending code like this but still)

```
// map.h
#ifndef MAP_H
#define MAP_H
class Map {public: int size = 20};
extern Map map;
#endif

// fruit.h
#ifndef FRUIT_H
#define FRUIT_H
#include "map.h"
class Fruit { public: int pos = 1; draw() {return map.size;} };
extern Fruit fruit;
#endif

// stone.h
#ifndef STONE_H
#define STONE_H
#include "map.h"
#include "fruit.h"
class Stone { public: draw() {return map.size * fruit.pos;} };
extern Stone stone;
#endif

// main.cpp
#include "map.h"
#include "fruit.h"
#include "stone.h"
Map map;
Fruit fruit;
Stone stone;
```

This is not how you are supposed to write code.

Comment: Yes, I have already added to `main.h` and also `#ifndef` and `#define` to all the files, but not posted here.

Comment: Have you removed `main.h` from the other header files? Because it's not going to work if you don't. It's not a good idea to have one header file include another, and that other header file to include the first one again.

Comment: As has already been said, please post real code. If you post fake code all that will happen is you'll get answers based on all the mistakes in the fake code.

Comment: Yes. I have updated the post with actual code. Please, revise

Answer (score 0):

Files (`*.h` or `*.cpp`) should only include files that they directly depend upon.

Files should not include files that they do not depend upon.

One way to break cyclical dependencies is to put the implementation in the `foo.cpp` source file instead of inline in the `foo.h` header file.

One way to break dependencies on global variables is to instead pass them in as parameters instead of having them hard-coded into the routines.

Use of a forward declaration can be used to avoid including an header file that is only used to declare the type.  Only when the details of the type, such as its methods and footprint, are not important.  Alas, forward declarations for template classes are trickier.

For the files in the OP example, here's an alternative implementation incorporating those suggestions.

## fruit.h

```
#ifndef FRUIT_H
#define FRUIT_H

class Map;

class Fruit {
public:
    int pos = 1;
    auto draw(Map const&) -> int;
};

#endif
```

## map.h

```
#ifndef MAP_H
#define MAP_H

class Map {
public:
    int size = 20;
};

#endif
```

## stone.h

```
#ifndef STONE_H
#define STONE_H

class Fruit;
class Map;

class Stone {
public:
    auto draw(Map const& map, Fruit const& fruit) -> int;
};

#endif
```

## fruit.cpp

```
// Identity.
#include "fruit.h"

// Other dependencies.
#include "map.h"

auto Fruit::draw(Map const& map) -> int {
    return map.size;
}
```

## stone.cpp

```
// Identity.
#include "stone.h"

// Other dependencies.
#include "fruit.h"
#include "map.h"

auto Stone::draw(Map const& map, Fruit const& fruit) -> int {
    return map.size * fruit.pos;
}
```

## main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "fruit.h"
#include "map.h"
#include "stone.h"

using std::cout;

int main() {
    auto map = Map{};
    auto fruit = Fruit{};
    auto stone = Stone{};
    map.size = 17;
    fruit.pos = 3;
    cout << "map.size is " << map.size << "\n";
    cout << "fruit.pos is " << fruit.pos << "\n";
    cout << "fruit.draw(map) is " << fruit.draw(map) << "\n";
    cout << "stone.draw(map, fruit) is " << stone.draw(map, fruit) << "\n";
}
```